# Terraform (A)lb redirect http -> https

Tags: terraform, elastic-load-balancer

If I get this right, lb_listener only accepts forward as valid action type. 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener.html
How do I configure a listener to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

i.e. this is the desired state in elb listener:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This functionality was added to the AWS provider and [released with 1.33.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1330-august-22-2018).

Here's how you'd set the default action on a load balancer listener with the [`aws_lb_listener` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener.html):

```
resource "aws_lb" "front_end" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.front_end.arn}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add redirects and fixed type responses with individual load balancer listener rules in the [`aws_lb_listener_rule` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_rule.html):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "redirect_http_to_https" {
  listener_arn = "${aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn}"

  action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-service.*.terraform.io"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: mmm... too bad :-(

Comment: The pull request looks pretty comprehensive and at a quick glance I can't see anything wrong with it. I'd be surprised if it isn't released in the next version of the AWS provider.

Comment: It was released, YAY! https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5344#issuecomment-415138537

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Not sure if this has changed since you've last updated your answer but it looks like the condition now needs to look like this:

condition {
    host_header {
        values = [
            "my-service.*.terraform.io"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: @ReubendeVries yep, that got updated in [v3 of the AWS provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-3-upgrade#resource-aws_lb_listener_rule). I've edited the answer to update for that. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Whenever we have to add a redirect to port 443, we need a ssl certificate where have you specified that